# MS Access (2010) Enable Design View

Tags: templates, ms-access, designview

I downloaded the Access template below for doing a home inventory:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=home%20inventory&ex=1&queryid=0d245f2a%2Dacdc%2D4161%2D92c8%2D8ba16a52ab32&AxInstalled=1&c=0#ai:TC101918100|

The design view is not visible, which is a bit of a nuisance.

Things I've tried:
1) In options/options/current database/ the check boxes (enable layout view & enable design changes for tables in Datasheet view) are both greyed out.
2) I've unblocked the file using Right-Click->Properties.
3) I've tried copying/exporting the objects to another database.  But can only copy/export the tables.
4) I've tried holding shift when opening the DB.
5) Enabling all trust permissions etc.

None of these work

Does anybody have any suggestions. (I'm using Office 2010)

Thanks

Comment: Remou has given you the correct answer. That template is a web template and those forms are thus restricted to layout mode. Web objects cannot overlap like they can for VBA forms. So, you are restricted to this new layout mode. In fact the layout mode was introduced in Access 2007 and thus it not really a new choice anyway. You can see a web database of mine in action in the following link xx and note how I switch to running the application 100% in a browser. So the template you are using can be published to the web and run from a browser. Browser forms must be built in this new layout mode.

Comment: opps - forot the link. Here is the video of a web database in Action in a browser: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but just in case someone is still looking for an answer, [this worked for me](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=219350). I converted the Projects Web Database.

The process is as follows:

- Create a blank "client" accdb database.
- Import all web tables, client forms, client reports from the template web database into the blank client accdb database.
- Close the client database and open the template web database.

(Now, you must individually create a client object from each web object. This can be a bit tedious.)

- Highlight the web object (a web form, for example) that you want to create a corresponding client object. Click the File Tab, then Save & Publish, then Save Object As, and finally click the Save As Client Object button. Give the Client Object a different name than the web object (add Client to the end of the name, for example).
- You will need to repeat these steps for each web query, web form, web report, and web macro in the template web database.
- Once every web object has a corresponding client object in the template web database, open up the "client" database and import all client objects that you just created. Rename the objects to their original names (remove the word "client" if you took my suggestion above).

Now you should have a working template database that you can change to you liking.

Answer (score 1):

Home inventory is set up as web forms and these do not have the same design view as the "normal" Access forms.

[Albert Kallal](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/accessdev/thread/aded6487-1183-49aa-ab9d-5be62a05587b) says:

> Unfortunately , there is no conversion utility.
>
> However, you can use those web forms with VBA or so called Access
>   client forms.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. create a new blank database
2. import all of the tables, queries, reports, macros, etc using the import wizard