# cant open Northwind template forms in design view

Tags: ms-access

I need to settup a database  for inventory control purposes.   I really like the free app that microsoft offers ("Desktop Product inventory database") , but I am unable to open the forms in design view and I am unable to export these forms to another database.  please advise what I need to do in order to open the forms in design view.thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

database link
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ctndirectdownload.aspx?AssetID=TC102483123&Application=AC&Version=14&Result=2

Comment: these might help you: -http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?p=1153601

-http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the Access 2010 sample databases, including Inventory, are set up as web databases. They do not have a design mode that matches the "normal" Access forms.

See: [MS Access (2010) Enable Design View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354951/ms-access-2010-enable-design-view/12355015#12355015)

Comment: You can still modify the forms, but you have to use layout mode. As noted, this is due to the template being a WEB database. You can see a web database in Action in the following video of mine in which I swtich to running the application 100% in a web browser. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI